# Plane is stuck in 2D, won't move in the y axis

Tags: modeling, vertices, transforms, 2d

I want to move the vertex in this direction[image]

But it won't let me. I can move it in the X and Z axis but not the Y, like the plane is stuck being 2D and won't enter the third dimension.

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: @arafium you uploaded the wrong file i think. it's a cube in the uploaded file. it's not what you show us in the screenshot.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Hide the cube and all will be revealed! :^)

Comment: oops i was pressing `Alt+H` to reveal everything coz i was thinking it was hiding XD

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie There's always one comedian here! :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because the scale of that object is all over the place, including the <kbd>Z</kbd> scale being zero! In <kbd>Object</kbd> mode, apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> > <kbd>Scale</kbd> and you'll find that it works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You deliberately set the scale of Z to zero which in reality does not exist. Set it to a non-zero value.

[image]